# make a grayscale heatmap from an image

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to make a heatmap from a grayscaled image with cv2. The problem is, I get a strange looking image with this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('test.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

hist = cv2.calcHist([img], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
hist2 = np.uint8(hist)

heat = cv2.LUT(img, hist2)

cv2.imshow('img', heat)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what do you mean by heatmap, but there are some colormaps in matplotlib which you can use to get similar results.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('test.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
colormap = plt.get_cmap('inferno')
heatmap = (colormap(image) * 2**16).astype(np.uint16)[:,:,:3]
heatmap = cv2.cvtColor(heatmap, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('heatmap', heatmap)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Also, you can use cv2.applyColorMap

```
image = cv2.imread('test.jpg', 0)
heatmap = cv2.applyColorMap(image, cv2.COLORMAP_HOT)
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is, I must use the calcHist function. I should get something like this: [link](https://i.gyazo.com/261a99cea318a74f7efdc548d3419b8d.png) from this: [LINK](https://gyazo.com/4d192a024289476df9d40ff505caf002)

Comment: Do you have any algorithm or source you're following? Share that too.

Comment: They just showed us the image I linked in the comments and told us to make it from the second image by using the calcHist function.